# How do I get the code from github playground to my powerbi dev tools

Tags: sharepoint, github, powerbi

http://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/playground/index.html

This is the website. The selection is LineClusteredColumnComboChart. Is there a way I can access this code so that I can edit it from the PowerBi Dev Tools?